# Removing item from array by property value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsmutablearray

I'm looking for the most efficient and memory friendly way.

Let's say I have an array of `Person` objects. Each person has a hair color represented by an `NSString`.  Let's then say I want to remove all `Person` objects from the array where their hair color is brown.

How do I do this?

Keep in mind that you cannot remove an object from an array that is being enumerated upon.

Comment: Are they sorted? Are there duplicates? Is this a theoretical question, or are you having specific performance problems with your code? If the latter, could you perhaps give more details? Also, to be clear, you are specifically referring to mutating an existing `NSMutableArray`, and not generating a new array that doesn't contain all the brown haired people in the original - is that correct?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are two general approaches. We can test each element and then immediately remove the element if it meets the test criteria, or we can test each element and store the indexes of elements meeting the test criteria, and then remove all such elements at once. With memory usage a real concern, the storage requirements for the latter approach may render it undesirable.

With the "store all indexes to remove, then remove them" approach off the table, we need to consider the details involved in the former approach, and how they will effect the correctness and speed of the approach. There are two fatal errors waiting in this approach. The first is to remove the evaluated object not based on its index in the array, but rather with the `removeObject:` method. `removeObject:` does a linear search of the array to find the object to remove. With a large, unsorted data set, this will destroy our performance as the time increases with the square of the input size. By the way, using `indexOfObject:` and then `removeObjectAtIndex:` is just as bad, so we should avoid it also. The second fatal error would be starting our iteration at index 0. `NSMutableArray` rearranges the indexes after adding or removing an object, so if we start with index 0, we'll be guaranteed an index out of bounds exception if even one object is removed during the iteration. So, we have to start from the back of the array, and only remove objects that have lower indexes than every index we've checked so far.

Having laid that out, there's really two obvious choices: a `for` loop that starts at the end rather than the beginning of the array, or the `NSArray` method `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` method. Examples of each follow:

```
[persons enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(Person *p, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([p.hairColor isEqualToString:@"brown"]) {
        [persons removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
}];

NSInteger count = [persons count];
for (NSInteger index = (count - 1); index >= 0; index--) {
    Person *p = persons[index];
    if ([p.hairColor isEqualToString:@"brown"]) {
        [persons removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
}
```

My tests seem to show the `for` loop marginally faster - maybe about a quarter second faster for 500,000 elements, which is a difference between 8.5 and 8.25 seconds, basically. So I would suggest using the block approach, as it's safer and feels more idiomatic.

Comment: according to this guy, enumerration can be slow: http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/nsarray-enumeration-performance

Comment: @ChoppinBroccoli The way I read those results, block enumeration is extremely fast. What in particular are you referring to? I may be wrong about the for loop being faster, though - I was really tired when I wrote that part and this morning was wondering if I hadn't transposed my numbers. I'll run them again and edit my post.

Comment: Actually I think you're right.  I wasn't looking at block enumeration, just regular enumeration.

Comment: Would be interesting to compare performance against `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` and `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`, see my answer below

Comment: @PierreHouston Tested against `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` & `removeObjectsAtIndexes`, @Carl's Answer is the best one. :]

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you're dealing with a mutable array and it isn't sorted/indexed (i.e. you have to scan through the array), you can iterate through the array in reverse order using [`enumerateObjectsWithOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW18) with the `NSEnumerationReverse` option:

```
[array enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // now you can remove the object without affecting the enumeration
}];
```

By going in reverse order, you can remove an object from the array being enumerated.

Answer (score 9):

```
NSMutableArray * tempArray = [self.peopleArray mutableCopy];

for (Person * person in peopleArray){

 if ([person.hair isEqualToString: @"Brown Hair"])
     [tempArray removeObject: person]

}

self.peopleArray = tempArray;
```

Or NSPredicate also works: http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

Comment: This is going to get *really* slow on bigger sets of data due to calling `removeObject:` which necessitates a linear search of the array.

Answer (score 5):

The key is to use predicates for filtering array. See the code below;

```
- (NSArray*)filterArray:(NSArray*)list
{
    return  [list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings){
        People *currentObj = (People*)evaluatedObject;
        return (![currentObj.hairColour isEqualToString:@"brown"]);
    }]];
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use predicates... `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hairColour == %@", hairColour]`

Answer (score 3):

try like this,

```
        NSIndexSet *indices = [personsArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            return [[obj objectForKey:@"hair"] isEqual:@"Brown Hair"];
        }];
         NSArray *filtered = [personsArray objectsAtIndexes:indices];
```

OR

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.hair=%@ ",@"Brown Hair"];
        NSArray*   myArray = [personsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSLog(@"%@",myArray);
```

Comment: The first example is the most efficient. The Objc.io people did a comparison and found predicate based sorting to be slow. If you tweak the first example to use indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:passingTest: instead and in the options send `NSEnumerationConcurrent` you'll get the best performance.

Answer (score 3):

If you're making a copy of an array with certain items filtered out, then make a new mutable array, iterate over the original and add to the copy on the fly, as others have suggested for this answer. But your question said removing from an existing (presumably mutable) array.

While iterating, you could build an array of objects to remove, and then remove them afterwards:

```
NSMutableArray *thePeople = ...
NSString *hairColorToMatch = ...

NSMutableArray *matchingObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
for (People *person in thePeople) {
  if (person.hairColor isEqualToString:hairColorToMatch])
    [matchingObjects addObject:person];
[thePeople removeObjects:matchingObjects];
```

But this creates a temporary array that you might think is wasteful and, more importantly, it's hard to see `removeObjects:` being very efficient. Also, someone mentioned something about arrays with duplicate items, this should work in that case but wouldn't be the best, with each duplicate also in the temporary array and redundant matching within `removeObjects:`.

One can iterate by index instead and remove as you goes, but that makes the loop logic rather awkward. Instead, I would collect the indexes in an index set and again, remove afterwards:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *matchingIndexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
for (NSUInteger n = thePeople.count, i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  People *person = thePeople[i];
  if ([person.hairColor isEqualToString:hairColorToMatch])
    [matchingIndexes addIndex:i];
}
[thePeople removeObjectsAtIndexes:matchingIndexes];
```

I believe index sets have really low overhead so this is nearly as efficient as you'll get and hard to screw up. Another thing about removing in a batch at the end like this is that it's possible that Apple has optimized `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` to be better than a sequence of `removeObjectAtIndex:`. So even with the overhead of creating the index set data structure, this may beat out removing on the fly while iterating. This one works pretty well too if the array has duplicates.

If instead, you really are making a filtered copy, then I thought there was some `KVC` collection operator you can use (I was reading about those recently, you can do some crazy things with those according [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/) & [Guy English](http://kickingbear.com/blog/archives/9)). Apparently no, but close, one needs to use KVC **and** NSPredicate in this somewhat wordy line:

```
NSArray *subsetOfPeople = [allPeople filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.hairColor != %@", hairColorToMatch]];
```

Do go ahead and create a category on `NSArray` to make things more concise for your code, `filterWithFormat:` or something.

(all untested, typed directly into SO)

Comment: Instead of for loop for generating indexes, would probably be better to use `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:`. Since array not being modified within the block it doesn't need `NSEnumerationReverse` and can use `NSEnumerationConcurrent`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayForStuff = ...

[arrayForStuff removeObjectAtIndex:[arrayForStuff indexOfObject:objectToRemove]];
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of explanation. When answering a six year old question with six other answers it is imperative to address what new aspect of the question your answer addresses, and to mention if the passage of time has changed the answer.